# Как обработать данные JSON с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net

У меня есть ajax запрос

```
    var permissions = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetPermissions", "Home")',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({ fileId: fileId }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            permissions.push(data);
        },
        error: function () { alert('error'); return false;}
    });

    console.log(permissions);
```

который вызывает метод

```
[WebMethod]
public async Task<string> GetPermissions(string fileId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     AppFlowMetadata appFlow = new AppFlowMetadata();


     var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, appFlow).
        AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

     if (result.Credential != null)
     {
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                ApplicationName = "Drive"
            });

            List<Permission> permissions = Google_Drive_MVC.Models.PermissionsHelper.RetrievePermissions(service, fileId) as List<Permission>;

            string answer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(permissions);

            return answer;
     }
     else
     {
            return null;
     }

}
```

как мне их теперь обработать, например вывести все e-mail адреса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Циклы:

```
if(data){
    for(var i in data[0]){
        console.log(data[0][i].emailAdress);
    }
}
```

или

```
if(data){
    data[0].each(function(indexInArray, valueOfElement){
        console.log(valueOfElement.emailAdress);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (data) {
  JSON.parse(data).forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.emailAddress)
  });
},
```